# How to add a new key/value pair in a nested Map using Immutable.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, immutable.js

I want to add a new key/value pair to a Map which is nested in another Map. If the key already exists it should get replaced.

I thought [mergeDeepIn()](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/mergeDeepIn) should to the trick but I get an "invalid keyPath" Error.

The state looks like this:

```
{
   "requests":{
      "1":{
         "title":"I have a question",
         "customerId":2,
         "messages":{
            "222":{
               "text":"Hello!",
               "senderId":1,
            },
         },
        ...
      },
      ...
   },
}
```

'requests' and 'messages' are immutable Maps.

I tried this:

```
const message = fromJS({
  "5": {
    text: "test",
  },
})
state.mergeDeepIn(['requests', 1, 'messages'], message)
```

The message should get added to the 'messages' Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immutability is a property of a data structure and means: After that data structure is created it will never ever change again. Adding or replacing a value from/to a `Map` means mutating the `Map`, which is exactly what immutable-js tries to prevent.

What you can do is create a new `Map` from your already existing one.

```
const {Map} = require('immutable');
m = Map({a:1});

Map({...m.toJSON(), b:2}) // Map { "a": 1, "b": 2 }
Map({...m.toJSON(), a:2}) // Map { "a": 2 }
m.set('a', 2) // Map { "a": 2 } , creates a new map same as line above
```